# What library implements asynchronous processing of messages?

Tags: c++, asynchronous

Help find a library that implements:

1) Publisher-Subscribers. Publisher sends (SendMessage - not WinAPI function) the message, not knowing how many subscribers will receive it, maybe 0.

2) Asynchronously. If there is a free flow, the subscriber (s) must start in parallel with the code after the SendMessage.

3) Smart pointers to parameters. The parameter for different message can have different type, created in the heap and is available to all subscribers to read. After all subscribers have worked, the memory allocated for the parameters is released.

4) The pool of threads. Thread is not removed after processing the message, and wait a new message.

5) Optional: Priorities, several threads pools and mapping messages to different pools.

Comment: you wrote `(SendMessage - not WinAPI function)`, but SendMessage() is a WinAPI function... what did you mean ?

Comment: I believe he means sending a message in the general publisher-subscriber sense, not the WinAPI function, SendMessage.

Comment: I want an analog function SendMessage, but the message processor must be running in multiple threads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [Boost.Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at the [ACE framework](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/ACE.html)

It might be a bit  overkill, but pretty good ...

```
my2c
```